# Gmail icon image from webmail address

Tags: php, email, gmail, webmail

For Gmail it is just user profile image if you're using gmail as sender address instead of domain  mail.

I'm wondering if it is possible to attach image for email message icon received to Gmail or any other address  from my website visitor web-mail, which in my case  is one of *roundcube*, *squirrelMail*, *horde* applications on host